# How to enable usb port using Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have 2 usb ports one on each side of my laptop. The one on the left is ENABLED but the one on the right side isn't,how do i enable it?

Comment: How do you know it is disabled?

Comment: It would be extremely abnormal for a USB port to be disabled

Answer (score 0):

If the USB port actually is disabled, it is probably at the BIOS level, and you would need to change the configuration there. You can find a basic guide to do that [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001554.htm).